# netty rxtx can not work with NioEventLoopGroup

Tags: netty, nio, rxtx

`netty rxtx` can not work with `NioEventLoopGroup`.
When use Oio it's ok and work fine, but change to Nio that code can't work.
This project have many rial port connection.
RXTX only work oio?

Netty 4.1.6, Java 1.8.0_112

```
EventLoopGroup event = new NioEventLoopGroup();
Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();

bootstrap.group(event);
bootstrap.channel(RxtxChannel.class);
bootstrap.remoteAddress(new RxtxDeviceAddress(device.getSerialPort()));
// 设置端口参数
if (device.getSerialBaudRate() > 0)
    bootstrap.option(RxtxChannelOption.BAUD_RATE, device.getSerialBaudRate());

// bootstrap.option(RxtxChannelOption.DATA_BITS,
// RxtxChannelConfig.Databits.DATABITS_8);
// bootstrap.option(RxtxChannelOption.STOP_BITS,
// RxtxChannelConfig.Stopbits.STOPBITS_1);
// bootstrap.option(RxtxChannelOption.PARITY_BIT,
// RxtxChannelConfig.Paritybit.NONE);
// bootstrap.option(RxtxChannelOption.READ_TIMEOUT, 3000);
// 等待时间量
// bootstrap.option(RxtxChannelOption.WAIT_TIME, 100);
// bootstrap.option(RxtxChannelOption.DTR, false);
// bootstrap.option(RxtxChannelOption.RTS, false);

bootstrap.handler(new ChannelInitializer<RxtxChannel>() {
    @Override
    protected void initChannel(RxtxChannel sc) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = sc.pipeline();
    // 空闲时间监测(秒)
    pipeline.addLast(new IdleStateHandler(120, 60, 60));
    // 创建基于报头和长度的解码器
    pipeline.addLast(new KSFrameLengthDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast(new KSFrameDecoder(coder));
    // 创建业务逻辑解码器
    pipeline.addLast(new SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Message>() {
        @Override
        public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        busy.set(true);
        Message msg = Message.newBuilder().setCommand(Command.CONNECT).build();
        msg.device = device;
        channel.writeAndFlush(msg);
        }

        @Override
        protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Message msg) throws Exception {
        received(msg);
        if (queue.isEmpty()) {
            busy.set(false);
        } else {
            channel.writeAndFlush(queue.poll());
        }
        }

        @Override
        public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) {
        if (evt instanceof IdleStateEvent) {
            IdleStateEvent e = (IdleStateEvent) evt;
            if (e.state() == IdleState.READER_IDLE) {
            restart();
            } else {
            busy.set(true);
            Message msg = Message.newBuilder().setCommand(Command.GET_DEVICE_DATE).build();
            msg.device = device;
            channel.writeAndFlush(msg);
            }
        }
        }

        // 异常
        @Override
        public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        // 出现异常时,记录错误,稍后重连
        Log.error(cause);
        restart();
        }
    });
    pipeline.addLast(new KSFrameEncoder(coder));
    }
});
ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect();
channel = future.channel();

Log.info("START" + device.getName());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes rxtx only works with OIO as its implementation makes use of blocking InputStream and OutputStream.